# T-SQL, Compare Record Property, Then Suusequent Date Compare

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL, and it looks like this:

```
FOO   BAR   DateTime
---   ---   ------
FOO1  BAR1  4/25/2014
FOO2  BAR2  4/24/2014
........
```

to any n number of records in the above format.

I am trying to write a query that first returns all records that meet two property conditions, say all the records where FOO = FOO1 and BAR = BAR1, then with those results, return the record that has the most recent value out of the DateTime column. There can be multiple records where FOO = FOO1 and BAR = BAR1, and I am trying to get the most recent based on the datetime field value.

Comment: you need just one data for most recent one ?

Comment: What if you have several records with the same most recent date?

Comment: yes, where FOO = FOO1 and BAR = BAR1, the most recent

Comment: The same date wont happen in my scenario

Comment: Btw, you have 2 tags MySQL & Sql Server. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if I understood the request correctly (and it is SQL Server) it would be something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 FOO, BAR, DateTime
FROM Table 
WHERE FOO='FOO1' AND BAR='BAR1'
ORDER BY DateTime DESC
```

WHERE condition limits the set, ORDER BY sorts the set in descending order by date and TOP 1 selects the most recent record.

Comment: what if i need it for 2 records FOO1/BAR1 and FOO2/BAR2?

Comment: @vav I asked OP this question. The reply was *"The same date wont happen in my scenario "*

Comment: but my question is different, this is not about the ties. What you do if I need to return 2 records, one for FOO1/BAR1 and one for FOO2/BAR2 with their own max datetimes? TOP 2 will not work, right?

Comment: In that case grouping would have to involved by FOO and BAR with MAX date selected

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FOO, BAR, Datetime FROM table WHERE Foo = 'FOO1' and Bar = 'BAR1' 
and DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DATETIME) from table WHERE Foo = 'FOO1' and Bar = 'BAR1')
```

Probably this...or any other answer...haha

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the answer in almost any dialect of SQL

```
select FOO, BAR, MAX(DateTime) from 
table_name
where 
FOO = 'FOO1'
and BAR = 'BAR1'
group by FOO, BAR
```

Answer (score -1):

As you said you need just one data , the following query should do it. Since you have tagged your question with MySql so its mysql solution.

```
select FOO, BAR, MAX(DateTime) from 
table
where 
FOO = 'FOO1'
and BAR = 'BAR1'
```

Comment: I don't understand this. group by and max() are on the same column? how it works?

Comment: yes @vav you are correct the group by does not need to be here. Thanks for noticing it Max() will do it since its on the same column